# Time-travelling woman becomes a successful baker in Germany

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, medieval

I read a book in which at least 2 people, a man & a woman, went back to late medieval Europe - Germany, I think. The woman landed on a road between villages & was picked up by a small town baker's son, also a baker, looking for a village where he could set up a baking business. They became business partners, she had coffee beans imported to go with his pastries, and things went so well, she decided to stay in that time period. I don't remember anything about the male time traveler & what he did.

Ring any bells?

Comment: "Time-travelling woman becomes a successful baker in Germany" - one day, this will be an actual newspaper headline.

Comment: HA! That is a good headline. I'm going to have to find a way to use that, either as a headline or maybe as a pick-up line someday!

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for ["The Skin Map" by Stephen R Lawhead](http://www.stephenlawhead.com/bright-empires-novels/the-skin-map.html). The woman's name is Wilhelmina, and the male is Kit Livingstone and I believe it's Prague rather than Germany, but other than that all the elements are there.

Comment: Thank YOU! Yes, you've got much more of it right than I did! I appreciate this!

Comment: You're welcome. One of my favourite books. And you could accept the answer by clicking the tick at the left.